# Guardar URLs en MySQL desde PHP al estilo bitly

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

Amigos, como guardar URL acortadas en MySQL desde PHP?
Quisiera que una URL en MYSQL sólo tenga caracteres alfanuméricos y una URL normal no posee solo esa característica. Alguna forma de acortar una URL en PHP estilo bit.ly?

Comment: el código de SQL inyection pueden meterlo en cualquier campo, no sólo en ese de las URL

Comment: por hoy sólo vamos con las URLs, alguna solución

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php